# Timertask with setText() don't work

Tags: java, android

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

....

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
        t1.setText("Tap to Start");
    }
}, 2000);
```

Everytime after the TimerTask get executed, the Application stop working

Comment: you need check the error logged in logcat

Comment: Your logcat probably does say _... can't change UI Elements from another thread..._. So you do not try to change it from another thread.